# Shape of biases in Transformer's Feedforward Network

Tags: transformer, feedforward-neural-networks, linear-algebra

In transformer network ([Vaswani et al., 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762)), the feedforward networks have equation:

$$\mathrm{FNN}(x) = \max(0, xW_1 + b_1) W_2 + b_2$$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d_\mathrm{model}}$, $W_1 \in\mathbb{R}^{d_\mathrm{model} \times d_{ff}}$, $W_2 \in\mathbb{R}^{d_{ff} \times d_\mathrm{model}}$.

We know that the biases $b_1$ and $b_2$ are vectors.

But, for the equation to work the shape of $b_1$ and $b_2$ must agree, i.e., $b_1 \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times d_{ff}}$ and $b_2 \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times d_\mathrm{model}}$.

My question: is it true that

$b_1 = \begin{bmatrix} (b_1)_{1} & (b_1)_{2} & \dots & (b_1)_{d_{ff}}\\ (b_1)_{1} & (b_1)_{2} & \dots & (b_1)_{d_{ff}} \\ \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\ (b_1)_{1} & (b_1)_{2} & \dots & (b_1)_{d_{ff}} \end{bmatrix}$
and
$b_2 = \begin{bmatrix} (b_2)_{1} & (b_2)_{2} & \dots & (b_2)_{d_\mathrm{model}}\\ (b_2)_{1} & (b_2)_{2} & \dots & (b_2)_{d_\mathrm{model}} \\ \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\ (b_2)_{1} & (b_2)_{2} & \dots & (b_2)_{d_\mathrm{model}} \end{bmatrix}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biases are vectors, and their shape should be $b_1\in \mathbb R^{d_{ff}}$ and $b_2\in \mathbb R^{d_\text{model}}$.

To verify that let's compute the shapes of the above formula (for simplicity we can exclude the $\max$):
$$\begin{align}
xW_1 &= (n\times d_\text{model})\times (d_\text{model}\times d_{ff}) = n\times d_{ff} \\
(xW_1)W_2 &= (n\times d_{ff})\times (d_{ff}\times d_\text{model}) = n\times d_\text{model}
\end{align}
$$

In practice, according to the underlying implementation the biases can be either:

1. expanded to match the batch dimensions, i.e. the vectors can be replicated $n$ times (equal to the batch size) - as you wrote;
2. summed element per element.
3. added directly to the weight matrix: this requires adding an extra dimension to both $x$ (the inputs) and $W$, like: $xW =  (n\times d_{model}+1)\times (d_{model}+1\times d_{ff})$.

In the first two cases, the biases are stored as vectors. I'm not aware of implementations that keeps the biases as matrices (i.e. replicated vectors) also because the batch size $n$ is not said to remain fixed: e.g. on inference it's tipically one.